# Is $routeChangeSuccess guarantied to be fired inside a newly instantiated controller?

Tags: angularjs, controller, angularjs-scope, angularjs-controller, angular-routing

Suppose we have an ***/example*** route and the ***ExampleCtrl*** associated:

```
.when('/example', {
    templateUrl : 'example.html',
    controller: 'ExampleCtrl'
})
```

&

```
ExampleCtrl = function(){
    $scope.$on("$routeChangeSuccess", function(){
       // is this guarantied to be called inside current scope?
    }
}
```

Most of the time the ***$routeChangeSuccess*** event will fire inside the newly created scope, but can I rely on this assumption?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to StackOverflow ;)

```
$scope.$on...
```

that bit stands for listening to event $broadcast. As long as you don't consume event and stop propagation on purpose you can be certain that event indeed will be fired on new scope

hope that answers your question

Comment: Thank you =D Seems like the angularjs version that I'm using has a bug, or something doesn't go well somewhere deep in my code. I'm using $routeChangeSuccess to call the function that pulls json data from a server, instead of just calling it inside the controller. But it fails to execute ~1/30 times, apparently in a random manner, so I just thought my understanding of $routeChangeSuccess may be wrong. Thanks for quick reply!

Comment: Maybe you can use service/factory for that part of your logic, I think it might be good for you

Comment: Meh, not needed, I just call the function directly :P